# How to access array of object in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

```
 { _id: ObjectId("6203ad7eee9d346bd2681d54"),
      
      OrderID: 'QfoO-124Q?458BW',
      Status: 'Successful',
      
      CustomerInfo:
 
       [ { 'first-name': 'Gillespie' },
         { 'last-name': 'Lozano' },
         { email: 'hamilton@msn.com' },
         { 'phone-number': 8863744 },
         { address: '39 Park Road, LINCOLN, LN84 2MG' }
       ],

      PurchaseDate: '20/02/2020',
      }
```

I want to query one of the objects inside the array of CustomerInfo for example how to get the value of the key email using the keys CartItems and email.? without outputting the whole document?

Comment: Is [this official document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/) what you are looking for?

Comment: Sorry but no, I'm looking to access any value in the nested array using just the key.

Comment: Can you supplement more? like what input you are using, what is the expected output. It is currently unclear what do you mean by "access" now.